# Galaxy Tab S2 is psuedo-bricked; will not get past activation process

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, factory-reset, setup-wizard

I have a Galaxy Tab S2, 8.0", Wi-Fi (SM-T713). I have flashed it with stock firmware (flashed SYSTEM, CACHE, HIDDEN, BOOT, and RECOVERY), and wiped /data ("Factory reset" in recovery). However, it is stuck in a "psuedo-brick".

I call it this because while it may not be "bricked", it can't get past the initial setup process, and therefore can't be used for anything useful.

The specific issue is after the "Welcome!" screen. I select "English (United States)", and then it asks to set up Wi-Fi. It is off, so I turn it on. I wait a few seconds, and it turns itself off, without detecting any networks.

It seems to make me select a Wi-Fi network to proceed, which of course I can't do.

The FRP lock is enabled, so I cannot boot into anything custom.

**How can I get my device to stop turning its Wi-Fi off?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be an incomplete flashing. The method I did used `heimdall` to flash the `system.img.ext4`, `cache.img.ext4`, `hidden.img.ext4`, `recovery.img`, and `boot.img` files. While this allowed for a bootable system, it did not have Wi-Fi capabilities.

The solution was to get the device's PIT file via `heimdall download-pit --output pit.file`, then view the PIT via `heimdall print-pit --file pit.file | less`. You'd then have to go through each entry (my tablet had 42), and flash the file specified to the partition specified. (If the entry has no file name or the file doesn't exist, skip it.)

I do not recall which partition did the trick (I rebooted only after flashing all of them), but Wi-Fi capabilities were brought back.